# MySQL, Remove duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

I need to remove duplicates from my table but MySQL is not working properly

```
Create table emp
( empID INT(5) PRIMARY KEY,
Pref01 int(1),
Pref02 int(1),
Pref03 int(1),
Pref04 int(1))
```

```
empID, Pref01, Pref02, Pref03, Pref04
=====================================
00011    1       2       0       0
00011    1       3       0       0
00022    1       1       0       0
00022    0       3       0       0
```

I need to keep these records

```
00011  1       3       0       0 
00022  0       3       0       0
```

also I need to keep any record with all pref null value 
this is my sql:

```
select empID 
FROM emp 
where max(Pref01) or max (Pref02) or max(Pref03) or max(Pref04) 
    or Pref01 is null or Pref02 is null or Pref03 is null or Pref04 is null
```

Comment: `max(Pref01)` is not a boolean expression. It's likely not doing what you expect.

Comment: Also... it's not clear in the question how you know which record to keep for a given empID. What are the rules that determine this?

Comment: I need to keep the record with max Pref number

Comment: From which column? For id 00022, which Pref01 matches, Pref02 and Pref04 are higher in one record, and Pref03 is higher in the other. Is it the sum of all of these that determines the record? Or do you test each in sequence until one is greater, and then the others don't matter?

Comment: I test each sequence until one is greater and then compere with other  Pref02 or Pref03 and keep the record with highest Pref number

Comment: If two record with same `empID` has same max Pref number, which record will you keep?

Comment: Why do you not have straightforward design Pref(empId,prefOrdinal,prefChoice)? The complexity of your query is a consequence your choice of a complex membership condition for rows in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is quite complicated, and with given information I have to make an assumption to answer it..
Assume there is no record with same `empID` have same maximal pref number...

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM emp AS A 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT empID, MAX(GREATEST(Pref01, Pref02, Pref03, Pref04)) AS MaxPref 
        FROM emp GROUP BY empID
    ) AS B ON A.empID = B.empID
WHERE
    (Pref01 = MaxPref OR Pref02 = MaxPref OR Pref03 = MaxPref OR Pref04 = MaxPref)
    OR 
    (Pref01 IS NULL AND Pref02 IS NULL AND Pref03 IS NULL AND Pref04 IS NULL)
```

If the assumption is not correct then the code will still show duplicate for `empID` with same max pref number more than one.. to fix it is much more complicated than this code..

Answer (score 0):

You can get your data using `GROUP BY` and `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT empID, max(GREATEST(Pref01, Pref02, Pref03, Pref04)) FROM emp GROUP BY empID
```

you can use this to find rows directly in emp table using `exists` or `in`